# If Statement Issues

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting

I'm new to scripting and I'm trying to send my self an e-mail if there are updates ready on the system. The way I wanted to do it is if yum check-update reports any packages, send me an e-mail and if not do nothing. This is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/null > /root/scripts/updates.txt

yum check-update > /root/scripts/updates.txt

updatecheck=$(cat /root/scripts/updates.txt | grep updates | grep -v mirrors)
updatestatus=$(echo "$updatecheck" | wc -l)

if [ $updatestatus == 0 ]
then
        mail -s "There are no updates for monitor01.aevhosting.com" email@address.com
else
        mail -s "There are updates for monitor01.aevhosting.com" email@address.com
fi
```

It is not doing anything it just hangs there and to get back to the command line I have to control+c to exit the script. I'm also tailing the mailog to see if it sends out anything but it's not. Not sure what is wrong here but ANY and ALL help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

Thank You

Comment: The first line seems unnecessary; the file will be created when you run `yum` on the next line.

Comment: Is `mail` command working for our command line?

Comment: `cat ... | grep` is an anti-pattern, `grep` accepts files just fine it doesn't need piped input.

Comment: check-update also returns an exit code for exactly this purpose. `0` is no updates are available, `1` on errors, `100` if updates are available.

Comment: Hello,Yes the mail command works and send out the email when I run that mail line by it self in the command line. I have done each line by it self and it all works by it self but when I put everything together as you see above it does not do anything and get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mail` is waiting for standard input to fill the e-mail body. Pipe something to it:

```
echo 'This is automated e-mail, do not reply' | mail -s "There are updates..." email@address.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help everyone I got it working with the suggestion from @choroba. I had to put the echo "test" before the mail command which I did below and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/null > /root/scripts/updates.txt

yum check-update > /root/scripts/updates.txt

updatecheck=$(cat /root/scripts/updates.txt | grep updates | grep -v mirrors)
updatestatus=$(echo "$updatecheck" | wc -l)

if [ $updatestatus == 0 ]
then
    echo "There are no updates for monitor01.aevhosting.com" | mail -s "Update Status" email@gmail.com
else
    echo "There are updates for monitor01.aevhosting.com" | mail -s "Update Status" email@gmail.com
fi
```

Again thank you for the help from everyone!!

Comment: It looks like what you're saying is that you used [choroba's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25937065/2088135). If that's the case, you should accept it, rather than posting your own solution.

Comment: I didn't mean to do so if that's the case. This was the first time using the site didn't know how to do that.